# How to import modules from a python directory set up like this?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a Python directory like this, and I am trying to import classes from `main_script.py`.

```
 - main_folder
   - main_script.py
 - resources
   - package_folder
     - class_files
       - class1.py
       - class2.py
       - class3.py
       - __init__.py
```

This is what I tried

```
sys.path.append('../resources/package_folder)
from class_files import *
```

But I get this error, "No module named 'class_files'"

Comment: You are using a relative path, and it will be relative to your process's current working directory, not necessarily where the `main_script.py` is located.

Comment: So how would I find that? I did print `sys.path` but I got a bunch of things, hard to pinpoint what the working directory is.

Comment: Edit: Yeah so I did print(os.getcwd()) and it says the working directory is where main_script.py is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a relative path in your `sys.path` which is relative to the process's current directory rather than the location of the `main_script.py` script itself.

You can use instead:

```
import sys
import os

sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),
                             '../resources/package_folder'))

from class_files import *
```

or if you prefer:

```
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(__file__)),
                             'resources/package_folder'))
```

Separately, you might also find that in your `__init__.py` you need:

```
__all__ = ['class1', 'class2', 'class3']
```